# How to install OpenCV 2.1 via MacPorts in 32-bit?

Tags: opencv, macports, 32-bit

if we do "sudo port install opencv" it works fine but it installs in 64 bit as default. How do I install in 32-bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an easy answer you should consider moving to [homebrew](http://abhinay.wordpress.com/2010/01/02/macports-to-homebrew-new-packaging-system-for-mac-os-x/), which installs the 32bits version by default.

Comment: Great, don't forget to mark my answer as the right one or even vote up if it helped you somehow.

Comment: In this link https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/opencv.rbit says that homebrew won't install video related dependencies for opencv. (At least that is what I think the formula says, it's the first time I'm trying to use homebrew). Is this correct? As I'm trying to use opencv for video analysis its critical for me that it will be able to read all sorts of video formats, and also work with the webcam

Comment: @Yair I don't know about video codecs, but I guarantee that OpenCV installed with homebrew has webcam support.

Comment: Do I need to uninstall macport in order to switch to homebrew?

Comment: It is preferable that you do.